# Схема не видит мой новый контроллер opencart 2.3

Tags: opencart

Создал свой новый контролер assembly/assembly.php :

```
   <?php
class ControllerAssemblyAssembly extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('assembly/assembly');
        $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_meta_title'));
        $this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));
        $this->document->setKeywords($this->config->get('config_meta_keyword'));

        $data['title'] = $this->language->get('title');
        $data['text'] = $this->language->get('text');
        $data['my_var'] = $this->language->get('my_var');

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home'),
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'href' => $this->url->link('assembly/assembly'),
            'text' => $this->language->get('text')
        );


        if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
            $this->document->addLink(HTTP_SERVER, 'canonical');
        }


        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/assembly/assembly.tpl')) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/assembly/assembly.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('assembly/assembly.tpl', $data));
        }``
    }
}
```

+ файл в language
+ файл в вьюхе assembly/assembly.tpl(хлебные крошки и вывод моих переменных ):

```
   <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

<?php echo $header; ?>

<ul class="breadcrumb">

    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>

</ul>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <?php echo $my_var; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Схема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все работает нормально.
Создал новую схему в админке и прописал роут assembly/assembly, что бы ее содержимое отображалось только на этой странице, добавил модули для отображения и сохранил...все сохранилось, но когда я перехожу на нее то контент со схемы не отображается т.к. роут работает, потому что header&footer + переменные отображаются.
ВОПРОС -  почему данные со схемы не отображаются на странице? Нужно ли в контроллере подключить еще что то?

а вот и ответ))

```
$data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
    $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
    $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
```